# Why do we use if(i==n-1) condition when we don't find the searched item in the array? How does it even work?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, if-statement

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter the number whose index no. you want to find " << endl;
    cin >> a;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] == a)
        {
            cout << "Its index no. is " << i << endl;
            break;
        }
        if (i == n - 1)
        {
            cout << "No. not found in Array" << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What's the use of the `if(i==n-1)` in this? How is it functioning? Please help!

Comment: n - 1 is that last valid index in the array.  Since i was just checked at the top of the loop, if it is the last index (n-1), then it outputs the message "Not found".

Comment: As far as I've seen, this code isn't a particularly common way of doing this in the first place. You'd normally call a function to find the element you're looking for (e.g., `std::find`, `indexOf` in some languages) and the `if` there would be a simple test of that function's return value.

Comment: Another way would be to simply change the `break` into a `return`, and then move the `not found` message after the `for` loop, eg: `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { if (numbers[i] == a) { cout << "Its index no. is " << i << endl; return 0; } } cout << "No. not found in Array" << endl;`

Answer (score 1):

Since your loop will go from 0 to n-1 and if the value is not there at the last element also, then the code is printing the message.

Answer (score 1):

This loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] == a)
    {
        cout << "Its index no. is " << i << endl;
        break;
    }
    if (i == n - 1)
    {
        cout << "No. not found in Array" << endl;
    }
}
```

is just a bad code that can confuse readers.

It could be rewritten the following way:

```
int i = 0;

while ( i < n && numbers[i] != a ) i++;

if ( i != n )
{
    cout << "Its index no. is " << i << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "No. not found in Array" << endl;
}
```

That is if the number is found in the array that is if the condition `numbers[i] != a` evaluates to false then it means that the target number is at the position i. Otherwise all elements of the array will be checked and in the case i will be equal to n because the valid range of indices is `[0, n - 1)`.

In the original loop if the target number is found within the for loop then the corresponding message is outputted and the control exits the loop due to the break statement. Otherwise if it is the last element of the array (that is with the index `n - 1`)  and it is not equal to the target number then it means that there no more elements in the array to compare. This iteration when i is equal to n - 1 is the last iteration so the element in the array that is equal to the variable a is not found.